# Angular testing async function generate error - 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm trying to test that two async functions. The problem is that one of the functions is called every 10 seconds automatically. I tried to use tick() or flush() but I still get the same error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue. How can I resolve it?
My code:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.openProgressDialog();
    this.getSubscription = this.getAll();
    dialogRef.close();

    this.postSubscription = interval(10000).subscribe(() => {
      this.sendAll();
      this.dataSource.data = this.jobs;
      this.table.renderRows();
    });
  }
```

The test:

```
test("test", fakeAsync(() => {
    const getSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "getAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const getSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.getAll(), "subscribe");
    const postSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "sendAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const postSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.sendAll([2]), "subscribe");
    component.ngOnInit();
    //tick();
    //flush();
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Answer (score 6):

In short, you DON'T need flush, you DO need tick() and you should add the following to the bottom of your test, following your expectations:

```
      discardPeriodicTasks();
```

This will clear out any remaining timers you have before executing the next test.

So in your example (edited for brevity):

```
test("test", fakeAsync(() => {

   const getSpy = ...

   component.ngOnInit();
   tick(10000);

   expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalled() . . .

   discardPeriodicTasks(); 
 }));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

If `this.postSubscription` is a public variable, you can unsubscribe in your unit test.

```
test("test", fakeAsync(() => {
    const getSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "getAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const getSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.getAll(), "subscribe");
    const postSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "sendAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const postSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.sendAll([2]), "subscribe");
    component.ngOnInit();
    //tick();
    //flush();
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // unsubscribe
    component.postSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }));
```

If it is private, you can unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy` and call it in the unit test.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.postSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
...
test("test", fakeAsync(() => {
    const getSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "getAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const getSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.getAll(), "subscribe");
    const postSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock, "sendAll").and.returnValue(of(jobs));
    const postSubscribeSpy = spyOn(otdRepositoryMock.sendAll([2]), "subscribe");
    component.ngOnInit();
    //tick();
    //flush();
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postSubscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // call ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe
    component.ngOnDestroy();
  }));
```